# Incremental Parsing from Handle in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, attoparsec

I'm trying to interface Haskell with a command line program that has a read-eval-print loop.  I'd like to put some text into an input handle, and then read from an output handle until I find a prompt (and then repeat).  The reading should block until a prompt is found, but no longer.  Instead of coding up my own little state machine that reads one character at a time until it constructs a prompt, it would be nice to use Parsec or Attoparsec.  (One issue is that the prompt changes over time, so I can't just check for a constant string of characters.)

What is the best way to read the appropriate amount of data from the output handle and feed it to a parser?  I'm confused because most of the handle-reading primatives require me to decide beforehand how much data I want to read.  But it's the parser that should decide when to stop.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the parseWith function in Attoparsec?

Comment: It helpful if you could describe or give examples of the type of prompts you are expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have two questions wrapped up in here. One is about incremental parsing, and one is about incremental reading.

Attoparsec supports incremental parsing directly. See the `IResult` type in `Data.Attoparsec.Text`. Parsec, alas, doesn't. You can run your parser on what you have, and if it gives an error, add more input and try again, but you really don't know if the error was an unrecoverable parse error, or just needing for more input.

In your case, usualy REPLs read one line at a time. Hence you can use `hGetLine` to read a line - pass it to Attoparsec, and if it parses evaluate it, and if not, get another line.

If you want to see all this in action, I do this kind of thing in [Plush.Job.Output](https://github.com/mzero/plush/blob/master/src/Plush/Job/Output.hs), but with three small differences: 1) I'm parsing byte streams, not strings. 2) I've set it up to pull as much as is available from the input and parse as many items as I can. 3) I'm reading directly from file descriptos. But the same structure should help you do it in your situation.